# Find textbox value in gridview of checked row using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have a Gridview having checkbox and textbox column.
How to retrieve value of textbox belonging to checked row .

```
var checkCheckBox = $("#<%=GrdV.ClientID %> [id*=chkOrder]");
            $(checkCheckBox).click(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

                  alert($(this).parent("tr").find($("[id *= txtboxQty]")).val()); 
             }
```

shows

**undefined.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this:

```
alert($(this).closest("tr").find($("[id*=txtboxQty]")).val());
```

here `.closest()` is been used to traverse up to the `tr` which is grand parent, because `.parent()` returns the parent dom node.